# Author's Comments in a Migrated Question's Answers Are Not Clickable

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, migration, highlighting

I found that this user (Culip) had a question migrated to Stack Overflow, but his User Name in the comments in the Answers section was not highlighted or clickable.

This threw me for a bit of a loop, as I use the highlighting to quickly glance to see where the author commented on answers.

Unfortunately, I am unsure if this happened because the comment was there *before* or *after* the migrate.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870263/how-can-i-write-like-x-either-1-or-2-in-a-programming-language-closed) to the question on Stack Overflow.

[image: SO Highlight-Click Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct; that user does not exist on SO until such time as they choose to create an account there.

Thus, there is nothing to link to, and the post has no real owner.